# Why is this route 404?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, router

I am trying to add a new route in Express. The route is 404.

I have tried to set the route like the others but am having issues.

```
var repomapRouter = require('./routes/repomap');

 ...

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

...

app.use('/repomap',repomapRouter);
```

This is my `routes/repomap.js` route

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/repomap/:vendor/:product/:image', function(req, res, next) { 
 res.render('repomap', { title: 'Repo Map'});
})

module.exports = router;
```

User clicks this link to hit the above listed route:

```
<a href="/repomap/${vendor}/${product}/${image}">Artifacts</a>
```

I am expecting my hbs template to render. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mounted the router at `/repomap` with the `use` call.

`/repomap` + `/repomap/:vendor/:product/:image` is `/repomap/repomap/:vendor/:product/:image`

Comment: Ah ha! Thank you sir